# If file exist add number at the end

Tags: vb.net

probably simple question but i can;t figoure it out how to do it. What i try to achieve is if the file exist i want to create file with (x). For instance myfile.csv exist then create myfile.csv(1) if this exist the create myfile.csv(2) and so on. What i did so far is this:

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\file.csv"

        If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
            filename = filename & "(1)"             '"C:\file.csv(1)"
            If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
                'C:\file.csv(2)
                '...
            End If
        End If
```

NEW CODE:

```
   Private Function SeachAndCreate(filePath As String) As String
        If File.Exists(filePath) Then
            Dim folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
            Dim fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
            Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath)
            Dim fileNumber = 0

            Do
                fileNumber += 1
                filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath,
                                        String.Format("{0}_({1}){2}",
                                                      fileName,
                                                      fileNumber,
                                                      extension))
            Loop While File.Exists(filePath)

            File.Create(filePath)

        End If

        Return filePath
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` statement, `filename = filename & "(" & cnt & ")"`.

Why not file(1).csv?

Comment: i did something like in main topic is this ok? (according to your mark)

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense (to me, at least) to increment the actual file name, and not the extension. So, `file.csv`, `file(1).csv`, `file(2).csv`, and so on..

Either way, you can do this in a loop.

```
Dim fileName As String = "C:\file"
Dim fileExtension As String = ".csv"
Dim fileNumber As Integer = 1
Do
    If Not (IO.File.Exists(fileName & "(" & fileNumber.ToString & ")" & fileExtension) Then
        'The file does not exist, do something..
        Exit Do
    Else
        'The file does exist, so increment and try the next one
        fileNumber = fileNumber + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Note that this does not check for the existence of a file without a number (for example, `file.csv`). I'll leave that part for you.

Comment: i did a version which checks it - see my main post

Comment: @StackUser, if it works, click the checkmark of one and upvote the ones that help.